# How to change/disable highlight color of breakpoint lines in Visual Studio 2012 RC?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2012 RC with a dark background in the editor. I am NOT using the dark color theme. I am using the light theme. When I set a breakpoint, the text changes to black and I can't see it. I unchecked “Highlight entire source line for breakpoints and current statement.” setting under 'Debugging'. In "Fonts and Colors" all the entries for 'breakpoint' and 'current statement' do not have a dark color for both foreground and background colors.

Where is the setting for this or is this a bug in VS?

Comment: Pretty old, but yea, I found out it controlled by the `Current Statement` display item under Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors.

Answer (score 33):

You can change the font color to white in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Breakpoint (enabled)`. That won't restore syntax highlighting, though.

Comment: Doesn't change the text color.

Comment: @DannyVarod, yes. That's what I meant by "That won't restore syntax highlighting, though."

Comment: it would be nice if one could set an alpha layer color on the Debug line so the code continues to show in its original colors (keep syntax highlighting)

Comment: visual  studio 2013 also has this issue, you need to restart it for the color to take effect

Comment: It works as well for Visual Studio 2015 but you must restart VS that is annoyed.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, no need to restart :)

Comment: My VS 2015 Update 2 still do need restart

Comment: thanks, works in VS 2019; the default colors are just way too much

Answer (score 2):

Still can't turn it off properly in VS2019 but there is hope in the form of an github issue. Go thumb it up & subscribe: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39114

You can change the color as mentioned above, but this will lose the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

check Options - Text Editor - General - Indicator Margin.
It should be checked, so Visual Studio can place the marker.

Answer (score 0):

As of Visual Studio 17.8, this feature has been added. `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Breakpoint (enabled)`. If you set the Item foreground to `Automatic` it restores syntax highlighting