# How do I prevent a Visual Studio breakpoint from highlighting to whole line in red?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I place a breakpoint in my C# code in Visual Studio 2022, the whole line is highlighted it red, and the text is all white, losing any syntax colouring.

I find this very excessive, and makes code hard to read. Is there a way I can disable this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change/disable highlight color of breakpoint lines in Visual Studio 2012 RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958928/how-to-change-disable-highlight-color-of-breakpoint-lines-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: I posted an answer, if it helps you, you can accept it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As tested you can prevent Visual Studio breakpoints from highlighting entire lines in red by:

Tools > Options >Environment > Fonts and Colors > Breakpoint (Enabled)

Set “Item foreground:” to “Automatic” (this keeps the original text formatting)

Set “Item background:” to whatever fits your colorsceme or keep it as is(I set it to black)

[image]

Test Results:

[image]